# Craft CLI ./craft - can I tell it to use a specific php version when running composer via the CLI?

Tags: cli

With the Craft CLI, is there a way to set which php version to use?

The context here is that the server runs PHP 5.4 for another project, but PHP 7.3 is installed at `/usr/bin/php73` and is setup in Apache to use that version for this specific site.

With normal `composer install` I just specify the path to that version like so:

`/usr/bin/php73 /usr/bin/composer update`

but I want to be able to run updates via the Craft CLI. The CLI tool then uses the composer version on the server. Is there a way to specify what version of php to use when running commands via the CLI?

Comment: What host/server/linux distro are you running on? This is something you will need to do server side.

Answer (score 1):

This is something I completely overlooked, but the Craft CLI is just a PHP wrapper that's executable on the CLI. So this will work:

`/usr/bin/php73 craft help`
or
`/usr/bin/php73 craft update all`

Will run the CLI with the PHP binary of your choice.